# Gradle Class-Path for executable jar

Tags: java, gradle, build, jar, dependencies

I want to generate an executable jar file of my java project with gradle. However I can’t figure out how to reference the jars of my dependencies because they sit in some cache directory outside the project. How can I get them into my project.

Those are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
// This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

// This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

// Use JUnit test framework
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.19'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.12.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.18.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.4.21.Final'
implementation 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.2'
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`application` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/application_plugin.html) which will take care of this for you.

In particular, this plugin has `distZip` and `distTar` tasks that will create a distribution for your application with the dependencies in a `lib` folder and startup scripts with the classpath setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I am copying my dependencies into the libs subdirectory in my build directory and iterate over them to get my classpath. The problem is that I want to exclue my resources from the jar because I want to be able to configure my project even when I only have my jar and the dependencies. Is there a smooth way to do this with the application plugin too?